# Ingress - Portal submissions

Tags: ingress

I apologise if this has been asked previously but I cannot find any updated information online since 2015.

I understand the submission of portals has been removed from ingress but have they given any news regarding their development of an improved feature? Are all niantics developers busy with pokemon now and they don't care about the game? The town I am in has quite a few portals but it's a pretty low density of portals compared to some of the towns which are close by. I'd quite like to improve that if possible.

Let me know if you have any updated information, thanks.

Edit: Apologies for writing a question which was classified as off-topic. I should have read the guidelines a bit better.

Answer (score 3):

For a short time there was a roundabout way to contact Niantic about new Pokestops/Portals via the "report a bug" contact form. However all submission were denied and this was their reply which should answer your question for the moment till Niantic tells us more.

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your interest in adding PokéStops and Gyms to Pokémon
>   GO. While we are not currently accepting new submissions, we will pass
>   your request along to our business development team and if they are
>   interested they will follow up directly.
>
> - NianticOps

Though there probably will be a way to add new Portals/Pokestops in the future, you shouldn't count on it this year. (And even in the case they do add the option, it took an Ingress portal between 3 months and 3 Years -with an average of 6 months- to be put up from the moment they were submitted. So don't count on new portals via submission on any time soon.
Sorry Mate.

I do hope they find a more intelligent and automated way to add more portals in the future.

Comment: This sort of anwers the question (since Pokemon and Ingress share a lot of Pokestops/portals), but doesn't really sound like an answer to a question about Ingress.

Comment: However, it's the best answer you're likely to get, since Niantic doesn't talk otherwise.